# Сайт вордпресс в подпапке /rus/

Tags: php, wordpress, index

Существует сайт на вордпресс sitename.ru , мне требуется создать отдельную версию, только для одной страны, которую будет перенаправлять на sitename.ru/rus/ . Проблема в том, что главная страница уже открывается по отдельной ссылке sitename.ru/rus/ , но все подстраницы выводят на sitename.ru/page , при том что основная ссылка в бд2 заменена на sitename.ru/rus/ и все подссылки заменены через бд на sitename.ru/rus/ . 
В чем может быть проблема ?

Так же в htaccess добавил , и страница перестала вообще работать

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /rus/
RewriteRule ^index.php$ – [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /rus/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1):

Для данной проблемы используйте или мультисайт https://wp-kama.ru/handbook/wordpress/ustanovka-multisite-mu или любой из плагинов для мультиязычности. Например: WPML https://wpml.org/ru/.